# jQuery: keyup and keydown event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to call the keydown and keyup event with JS. Howvever I get a syntax error. What's missing in the code?

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="ryu">
        <div class="ryu-still"></div>
        <div class="ryu-ready"></div>
        <div class="ryu-throwing"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="ryu-cool"></div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.ryu-cool {
    display: none;
    background-image: url('http://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/03/c5/42/a4/rainbow-spirit.jpg');
} 

.ryu-still {
    background-image: url('http://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/03/c5/42/a4/rainbow-  spirit.jpg');
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.ryu').keydown(function(e){
        if(e.keyCode == 88){
            $('.ryu-still').hide();
            $('.ryu-cool').show(); 
        })

    .keyup(function(e){
        if(e.keyCode == 88){
            $('.ryu-still').hide();
            $('.ryu-cool').show(); 
        });
     });
 });
```

The JSfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/3Ppdf/

Comment: `if(){` missing end `}`. Also extra `})`. copy paste? There is a `tidy up` uption available in Jsfiddle

Answer (score 2):

Along with the code formatting issues other have pointed out, the code still won't function as expected without a small addition.

Working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3Ppdf/4/)

You will need to add a tab index to the `<div>` element that you want to monitor keyboard input on.

Your HTML should look like this:

```
<div class="main">
    <div tabindex="0" class="ryu">
        <div class="ryu-still"></div>
        <div class="ryu-ready"></div>
        <div class="ryu-cool"></div>
        <div class="ryu-throwing"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The JavaScript will also need to be updated to:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.ryu').keydown(function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 88) {
            $('.ryu-still').hide();
            $('.ryu-cool').show();
        }
    })
    .keyup(function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 88) {
            $('.ryu-still').show();
            $('.ryu-cool').hide();
        };
    })
});
```

Also, to get the images to display properly you have to give the `<div>`s an explicit width and height:

```
.ryu-cool {
    display: none;
    background-image: url('http://www.theprojectors.co.uk/img/p/187-219-thickbox.jpg');
    width: 600px;
    height: 600px;
}
.ryu-still {
    background-image: url('http://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/03/c5/42/a4/rainbow-spirit.jpg');
    width: 550px;
    height: 364px;
}
```

Otherwise the `<div>`s will have a width and height of zero and therefore not displayed on the page.

Comment: You need to provide more details if you want help fixing the problem. Also, you have to click on the `<div>` to give it focus before you can listen to events on that `<div>`.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the ending bracket for the `if` statements. Your code should be this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.ryu').keydown(function(e){
        if(e.keyCode == 88){
            $('.ryu-still').hide();
            $('.ryu-cool').show(); 
        }
    })

    .keyup(function(e){
        if(e.keyCode == 88){
            $('.ryu-still').hide();
            $('.ryu-cool').show(); 
        }
     });
});
```

See updated JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3Ppdf/3/

Comment: thanks, it solved the syntax error but I can't get the methods to work when I press key "x".

Comment: What's the "updated jsfiddle" supposed to do? For me it's just an empty screen and nothing happens regardless of what keys you press.

Comment: @Juhana You're right...there were additional errors as HJ05 mentioned in his answer. This fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3Ppdf/5/ fixes some, but not all of them.

Comment: @Juhana try this link and hold down "x". I'm not sure if you can see it. That's what its supposed to do. Its not not working at my end.

Comment: @ALH Yes, I know what you're aiming at. I was commenting to apparatix. In any case you should bind the keydown event to the document (`$(document).keydown(...)`) because the focus is usually not in divs; that's what the streetfighter example does.